# How to pass html string to webview on android?

Tags: android, webview

I am parsing xml and then loading it to web view. After parsing, I am creating four strings so that I could append all strings to one view. I am able to get two views on the web view, but not the first two strings.

Please suggest in my code, where I am going wrong and the correct way to get the formatted html strings on the web view.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String chapterTitle = "";
        String SubChapterTitle="";
        String chapterIntro ="";
        String chapterContent="";
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // view = inflater.inflate(resourceid, null);
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.webviewitem, null);
        }
        synchronized (view) {
            WebView wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.contentWebView);

            WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
            // wv.setBackgroundColor(0);
            wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            /*String txtChapTitle = Intro.book.getsecretList().get(position)
                    .getChtitle().toString();*/
            
            if (!(Intro.book.getsecretList().get(position).getChtitle()
                    .toString().equals(""))){
            chapterTitle = "<b><fontSize=4>"+Intro.book.getsecretList().get(position)
            .getChtitle().toString()+"</font></b>";
            }
            if (!(Intro.book.getsecretList().get(position)
                    .getSubtitle() == null)) {
                SubChapterTitle = "<b><fontSize=4>"+Intro.book.getsecretList().get(position)
                .getSubtitle().toString()+"</font></b>";
            }
            if (!(Intro.book.getsecretList().get(position)
                    .getIntro() == null)) {
            chapterIntro = "<b><fontSize=2>"+Intro.book.getsecretList().get(position)
                .getIntro().toString()+"</font></b>";
            }
            if (!(Intro.book.getsecretList().get(position)
                    .getContent() == null)) {
            chapterContent = "<fontSize=2>"+Intro.book.getsecretList().get(position)
                .getContent().toString()+"</font>";
            }
            
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            content.append(chapterTitle+SubChapterTitle+chapterIntro+chapterContent);
            
            JsInterface Jsi = new JsInterface();
            Jsi.wordDef = content ;
            Log.v("Content", "" +content);
            wv.addJavascriptInterface(Jsi, "interfaces");

            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
                }
            });

            wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url,
                        String message, JsResult result) {
                    return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
                }
            });
            
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/wordview.html");
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

I am able to get `chapterIntro` and `chaptercontent` on the web view, but not the first two strings.

Answer (score 234):

i have successfully done by below line

```
 //data == html data which you want to load
 String data = "Your data which you want to load";

 WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webview.loadData(data, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Or You can try

```
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: do you add this to the <head> on the index.php/index.html?

Comment: ya if you want to, otherwise it will be ok

Comment: It updates the UI after a little lag. How to fix that thing?

Comment: can i use "text/html", "UTF-8", if i want to pass the html to javascript function  using webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyFunction( data, "text/html", "UTF-8")?

Comment: No I haven't used like this

Comment: @siddhpura Amit i have large html source code i want to pass it to javascript without error how to do it ? should we serialize it before passing it ?

Comment: Hi, you can put that file in asset directory and use below code for load that data webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourhtmlfile.html");

Comment: @PanchalAmit Enabling JS without actually using it leads to security issue and is not recommended. Can you update this also in your answer

Answer (score 180):

To load your data in WebView. Call loadData() method of WebView

```
webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

You can check this example

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: i tried with that, still not happening also tried with loadbaserul

Comment: is that supposed to work with a string containing javascript? It's not working for me

Comment: it should be `webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");`

Comment: The "text/html; charset=utf-8" makes a big difference, symbol characters don't render properly without it.

Comment: String htmlData = "Your HTML String";
                            mWebView.loadData(htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8");

Answer (score 43):

Passing null would be better. The full codes is like:

```
WebView wv = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html>...</html>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: do you add this to the <head> on the index.php/index.html?

Comment: @mthethelelibeseti this is Android codes, not HTML's. Or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: It is the working solution for all types of html strings. Thanks @JeffreyNeo

Comment: Really correct answer! Above answers did not work for me, but this answer worked for me. Thanks @JeffreyNeo

Answer (score 8):

I was using some buttons with some events, converted image file coming from server.
Loading normal data wasn't working for me, converting into Base64 working just fine.

```
String unencodedHtml ="<html><body>'%28' is the code for '('</body></html>";
tring encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedHtml.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
webView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
```

Find details on  [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: +1 for encoding the HTML. You can additionally pass the correct charset into `getBytes()` like this: `unencodedHtml.getBytes("UTF-8")` and define the charset in the MIME type like this: `"text/html; charset=utf-8"`.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling the 2 hours of effort I found the solution

I want to run this code in webview

```
"<div style='width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:56.250%;background:#000;'><iframe src='https://www.scorebat.com/embed/v/N09DWllRdlNraERnSXRRa1VJMTF4Zz09/?token=MTkxMTdfMTY1MjEyMzY2MF9kNzRkZTI4MTc3ZDAxZTNkOTQyOTg1OWE3MTcyYmFhY2EyYTI2YTZh&utm_source=api&utm_medium=video&utm_campaign=apifd' frameborder='0' width='100%' height='100%' allowfullscreen allow='autoplay; fullscreen' style='width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;'></iframe></div>"
```

But I only got the white screen after trying all the answers

Now do this as your code will also work

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Here  webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null); data is the HTML and javascript code

Add this line in your application tag as well

android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

I hope it will solve your issue