# How to show SQLiteDatabase query result as html on android?

Tags: java, android, html, dictionary

My searchable dictionary (Google's `SearchableDictionary` found on SDK/samples) gets its query result from `SQLiteDatabase` which gets data from `definitions.txt` file (Its .txt file not `XML` file).

Now I want want to show query results output as `Html` on android. that mean, I want to ad `\n` `<b>` and other `Html code` on `definitions.txt` which will prossesed on SQLiteDatabase give output on query. I've found a code `.setText(Html.fromHtml` but it supposed to work on XML strings only.

Here is My code which shows final output on my project

```
TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
```

Comment: we are not getting you.

Comment: In a word, I want to show "SearchableDictionary"'s result as HTML so that i can add line breaks and other tags.

Comment: Well, at least you should write your own html constructor logic which accepts results from DB query.

Comment: @alex-bonel: I did not write any html constructor, because I've no idea. Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- fetch the text you need
- append html tags to your text
- encode the string to html format - See Tip 1 below.
- display the encoded html in a textview (WebView if you want to render the HTML) - See Tip 2 below.

**Tip 1:** You can use the htmlEnode() method from TextUtils class to encode a string to HTML. [See tutorial here.](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/html-encode-string-using.html)

**Tip 2:** [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987509/how-to-pass-html-string-to-webview-on-android) to find out how to load HTML encoded data into a webview.