# how to show string in mhtml format in a webview?

Tags: android, webview, mhtml

I have a string which contains the contents of a web page in `mhtml` format.

Now I want to display this web page in a Webview for Android devices:

```
String str = "..."; // this is the mhtml document
webView.loadData(str,"text/html",null);
```

But this displays the `mhtml` markup instead of parsing it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass html string to webview on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987509/how-to-pass-html-string-to-webview-on-android)