# webview cant access sdcard

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm new to android studios, the problem i'm facing is that I have saved a html file in raw file and accessing it in activity using webview, when app opened it will ask to open file from sdcard but when touched it does nothing stays in same page, I have included sd card read permission in manafist. pls help, thanks in advance.

[Screen shot of my page][1]

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here when pressed browse your phone its not doing anything.

Here is my java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private WebView webView;
    private String  myString= "", customHtm="";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);



         webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/simp.html");



    }


}
```

[this is what i Intend to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WM08.png)
 simply when link is pressed i want this in built action to happen,

Comment: off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*** ... you didn't include html file

Comment: I would try loading the resource into a string or buffer (depending on size) then using WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL like http://stackoverflow.com/q/8987509/418505

Comment: *I would try loading the resource into a string or buffer* <= programming by permutation? ... the file is loading with loadUrl, so why using loadDataWithBaseURL?

Comment: I probably misunderstood the question, if the page is loading then the issue lies elsewhere

Comment: i would add more pictures , but its asking i must have 10 reputation, hope my edit clears the question

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    final Activity activity = this;
    public Uri imageUri;

    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE   = 2888;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get webview
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

        // Define url that will open in webview
        String webViewUrl = "file:///android_res/raw/simp.html";


        // Javascript inabled on webview

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Other webview options
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        //Other webview settings
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);

        // Define Webview manage classes
        startWebView();
    }

    private void startWebView() {
        // Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
        // Called When opening a url or click on link
        // You can create external class extends with WebViewClient
        // Taking WebViewClient as inner class

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            //If you will not use this method url links are open in new brower not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                // Check if Url contains ExternalLinks string in url
                // then open url in new browser
                // else all webview links will open in webview browser
                if(url.contains("google")){

                    // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                    //Open links in new browser
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                    // Here we can open new activity

                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Stay within this webview and load url
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            }


            //Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

                // if url contains string androidexample
                // Then show progress  Dialog
                if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("androidexample")
                        ) {

                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }

            // Called when all page resources loaded
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                try{
                    // Close progressDialog
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // You can create external class extends with WebChromeClient
        // Taking WebViewClient as inner class
        // we will define openFileChooser for select file from camera or sdcard

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){

                // Update message
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

                try{
                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

                    File imageStorageDir = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                            , "AndroidExampleFolder");

                    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    // Create camera captured image file path and name
                    File file = new File(
                            imageStorageDir + File.separator + ""
                                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                    + ".stl");

                    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

                    // Camera capture image intent
                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("*/*");

                    // Create file chooser intent
                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Chooser STL file to view");

                    // Set camera intent to file chooser
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                            , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

                    // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            //openFileChooser for other Android versions
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                        String acceptType,
                                        String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }


            // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a
            // console message informing what action to perform,
            // taking a photo or updating the file

            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                return true;
            }

            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
                //Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message);
            }
        });   // End setWebChromeClient
    }


    // Return here when file selected from camera or from SDcard

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }

            Uri result=null;
            try{
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    // Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

In the code, it's asked to choose general file means not specific such as jpg, mp3 so it opens up general file chooser. You have to pick manually what it needs to pick.

If you need to pick pictures, replace

```
i.setType("*/*");
```

by

```
i.setType("image/*"); // image with all extension
i.setType("image/png"); // for PNG
```